# Difference between "$G$ acts on $A$" and "G is a permutation group on $A$ (i.e. $G\leq S_A$)"

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

This question is inspired by questions $4.1.1$ and $4.1.2$ of Dummit and Foote. The hypothesis for the first question is formulated as: "Let $G$ act on the set $A$", and the hypothesis for the second question is formulated as "Let $G$ be a permutation group on $A$".

I know that $G$ acting on $A$ induces a permutation representation of $G$, which is a homomorphism of $G$ into $S_A$. This means that $G$ is homomorphic to some subgroup of $S_A$.

So I think the difference between the hypothesis that in the second hypothesis $G$ must not only be homomorphic, but isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_A$?

Please confirm this or explain what I'm missing here. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Distinct elements of a permutation group act differently, but in general with a group action distinct elements *may* act the same (equivalently, the map $G\to S_A$ needn't be injective).

Comment: A group action is a map that lets each element of $G$ act as a permutation on the elements of $A$. In that way, if $G$ acts on $A$, then $G$ /is/ a permutation group on $A$. In these two exercises, it seems like the difference is in the first one we ask about the structure of the action of $G$ on $A$ and in the second exercise it asks about the structure of $G$ itself given that $G$ acts on $A$.

Comment: @walker No, see my comment.

Comment: @whacka So you're saying that if $G$ acts on $A$, we only view $G\le S_A$ if the action of $G$ on $A$ is faithful?

Comment: @walkar Right, $G$ cannot be considered a permutation group if the action is not faithful.

Comment: @whacka That makes sense. Ignore my comment, OP. You should probably write this as an answer.

Comment: @whacka Oke thanks!

Comment: @walkar This was exactly my initial reasoning. But then I though that there must be SOME difference between the formulations. So thanks for your input and discussion with Walkar, thereby shedding definitive light on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A permutation group is automatically a subset of $S_A$. Equivalently, it is an embedding $G\to S_A$, which means this group homomorphism must be injective (aka one-to-one). In general, a group action needn't be specified by an injective map $G\to S_A$. If the map is not $1$-to-$1$, then different elements of $G$ are sent to the same permutation, so they act the same way on $A$, whereas distinct permutations always act differently on $A$. The term for this is an unfaithful action.

Comment: But it is also worth noting that if we mod out by the kernel of the action we obtain a subgroup of $S_A$ if the action is not faithful.